# Adding data based on datetime index

Tags: python, dataframe, addition, datetimeindex

I have the below code

```
dateseries=pd.date_range('1996-10-31','2019-01-05',freq='B')
df1['Date']=pd.DataFrame(dateseries,columns=['Date'])
```

I want to add a column for sum for each date in this dataframe (df) from another dataframe (say df2, that has multiple values for same date) based on date filters

```
df1
Date
1996-10-31
1996-11-01
1996-11-02

df2
Date       Val   
1996-10-31   5
1996-10-31   6
1996-10-31   4
1996-11-01   7
1996-11-01   9
```

I want the final output in df1 as below

```
df1
Date        Val
1996-10-31   15
1996-11-01   16
```

Comment: Hello Prakash, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using .loc and specify dates, it was working if datetime index is not there. since I have a datetime index, I'm not able to specify location based on .loc

Comment: I'm a new user in python, just learning for the past two days

Comment: This is not really Python but Pandas. And what you want is probably the `groupby` method of Pandas dataframes. What about `df2.groupby('Date').sum()`?

Comment: Thanks Serge. That's helpful